# plotting a graph with unnormalized result

Tags: python-3.x

I just plot 2 columns of my data and the attached figure shows the result, why I get such a strange graph?
[image]

```
    from datetime import datetime
    df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%d/%m/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p')
    df.info()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.plot(df['Timestamp'], df['Total Fwd Packet'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the timestamps are not sorted, so the lines are joining up different times.

A quick solution is to plot without the lines by adding `linestyle='none', marker='.'` in `plt.plot(...)`.

To fix the problem of unsorted timestamps, you need to `.sort_values`:

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='Timestamp')

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.plot(df_sorted['Timestamp'], df_sorted['Total Fwd Packet'])
plt.show()
```

This will give you a sorted df, which you can plot with lines and it'll be in the right order.